# React-Native custom button

Tags: user-interface, button, react-native

How Do I create that Button?

[image: Button]

I tried the [wix ui lib](https://wix.github.io/react-native-ui-lib/docs/Button/), and I was able to get the border radius and shadow but I cannot set the **gradient** for the background. 
My second approach was to export the design file of the button (svg) to png and pass it to a `<ImageBackground />` but that looks really ugly in terms of wrong size. But even when I export it in a really big format, It looks stupid too, so this is not an option for me. Does somebody might know how to get to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping your button around this lib

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-linear-gradient

Try this code

```
<LinearGradient colors={['#Color1', '##Color2', '##Color3']}
style={styles.YourPaddingStyle} 
          start={{ y: 0.0, x: 0.0 }}
          end={{ y: 0.0, x: 1.0 }}>
  <YourButton style={styles.YourButton}>
  </YourButton>
</LinearGradient>
```

Comment: use this to get a horizontal gradient start={[0, 0]} end={[1, 0]}

Comment: This lib doesnt work with my environment, react native 0.53. It tells me thatBVLinearGradient is missing. I think the supported version of react native is 0.40. So unfortunately this is not a solution to me.

Comment: Correction: had to rebuild my project. This works! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ART Library.

```
import {
    ART
} from 'react-native';

class Circle extends React.Component {

    render() {
      const {radius, ...rest} = this.props

      const circle = ART.Path()
        .move(radius, 0)
        .arc(0, radius * 2, radius)
        .arc(0, radius * -2, radius)

      return <ART.Shape {...rest} d={circle} />
    }
  }

const linearGradient = new LinearGradient({
            '0': '#EC6474',
            '1': '#7F5CFA'
         },
          "0", "0", "300", "0"
        );


 <ART.Surface width={200} height={200}>
            <ART.Group x={0} y={0}>
                <Circle radius={100} fill={linearGradient} />
            </ART.Group>
        </ART.Surface>
```

Result:

[image: Circle]

You are going to have to play a little bit with the path and also to link the ART library to your project but it is already included in RN.